# Trying to avoid showing private attributes in a header without pimpl

Tags: c

I consider my header file to be an interface of my module. I really dislike showing my users things they don't need to see in my interface.

The C folks do that by predeclaring structs and having the functions pass around pointers to that struct.

Which is perfect, except when there is a part of the struct that is public. My users need to be able to access it and modify it freely.

One solution is to do setters and getters and pass a pointer to the struct to which we don't show a definition.

We could also do like the c++ pimpl thing where we would have a pointer to an internal struct in our external struct. Again showing stuff in the interface that we shouldn't be showing.

And then I have an idea. And I want your input. Tell me if you think it's good or bad.

thing.h:

```
/// Must use thing_init() or bad will happen
struct thing
{
    int public_attribute;
};

typedef struct thing thing;

thing*
thing_init();
```

thing.c:

```
struct internal
{
    int private_attribute;
};

typedef struct internal internal;

thing*
thing_init()
{
    void* mem = malloc(sizeof(internal) + sizeof(thing));

    internal* i = (internal*)mem;
    thing* t = (thing*)(mem + sizeof(internal));

    // Initialize stuff

    return t;
}
```

Sooo the idea is like how malloc does things basically. What could go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is broken. For example should the public part have a `double` and the private part just a `char`, the arithmetic would cause the the public part to be misaligned.

---

What you can use and *should* use is the common initial prefix:

```
struct thing {
    int public_attribute;
};

struct internal {
    struct thing public;
    int private_attribute;
};

struct thing *thing_init()
{
    struct internal *mem = malloc(sizeof(struct internal));
    internal->public->public_attribute = 6 * 9;
    internal->private_attribute = 42;

    return &interal->public;

    // or
    return (struct thing *)internal;
}
```

I.e. the public part is the first member of the entire structure. This technique is well-defined in C.

Then in all functions that get in `struct thing *` you cast this pointer to `struct internal *`, and are ready to use the public and private members.

This technique is used e.g. by the CPython interpreter, where all Python objects in C code share a common initial sequence of `PyObject` followed by private parts.

Comment: Thanks for showing this idea, I didn't know that CPython uses it. It should work well as long as no-one creates an object of `struct thing` and gives that as an argument.

Comment: @thebusybee what Python additionally does is code the *type* of the object into the common prefix, to allow for polymorphism, so a function can deduce if it has been given a "thing" or "widget" or "gadget"